# jasper report pdf prints empty blank pages after filled page

Tags: jasper-reports

In jasper reports, while generating pdf it generates empty blank pages after filled page. The empty page count increases everytime while printing again and again.

Comment: Normally it doesn't. Thus, there is some detail in your very use of JasperReports which causes that. So please provide more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I checked in cross browsers, But the empty page count carried over to other browsers too. I'm using crosstab and report v3.0 tool to generate jasper. This only occurs while using crosstab only.

Comment: Which browsers are you using? Your question was about PDF reports, do I would assume that PDF viewers are relevant.

Comment: Yes, I am using Firefox v33. 1 and IE v11.0 and I used to open report using the browser plugin.

Comment: Ok, so that is clarified. Now to help you, please provide details to reproduce your issues because there usually aren't any such empty pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using doing like this:

```
JasperPrint  jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters);
```

Then you have to do this instead:

```
JasperPrint  jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

You have to provide a JREmptyDataSource.